# Why is the data in my database not updating?

Tags: php

I am trying have a form update a row in my database. I click on one of the options for the first time, both choices get filled with '1'. Every click afterwards does nothing. I've checked a site to see if my syntax is correct and it said there were no errors. I haven't been working with PHP for long, so I don't really know where I would've gone wrong.

I'm sorry if the fix is super simple but as I said, I haven't been doing this for long.

The options are mine and my friend's names, and so I have censored them.

```
<?php
include_once('db_feat.php');

$vote1 = $_POST['friend'];
$vote2 = $_POST['me'];
$vote = '';

$select = "SELECT * FROM `vote` WHERE 1";
mysqli_query($db_feat, $select);

$currentfriend = $row['friend'];
$currentme = $row['me'];

$finalfriend = '';
$finalme = '';

if($vote == $votefriend) {
    $finalfriend = $currentfriend + 1;
} else {
    $finalfriend = $currentfriend + 0;
}
if($vote == $voteme) {
    $finalme = $currentme + 1; 
} else {
    $finalme = $currentme + 0;
}

$insert = "UPDATE `vote` SET `friend`=$finalfriend,`me`=$finalme WHERE 1";
mysqli_query($db_feat, $insert);

if (!mysqli_query($db_feat,$insert)){
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($db_feat));
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>index.php</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Media/Images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/divs.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css">
    </head>

<body>
    <?php include_once('template_pageTop.php'); ?>
    <div id="pageMiddle">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="poll">
                <form action="index.php" method="post">
                    <input type="image" src="Media/Images/votefriend.png" name="friend" id="friend">
                    <input type="image" src="Media/Images/voteme.png" name="me" id="me">
                </form>
            </div>

            <?php echo $finalfriend; ?></br />
            <?php echo $finalme; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php include_once('template_pageBottom.php'); ?>
</body>
```

Here is the code I got from my database.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vote` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`friend` int(11) NOT NULL,
`me` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Comment: your query is totally irregular. where 1 = $final1? What the hell is this? First post the structure of your table then we will be able to suggest.

Comment: have you checked what `$_POST['1'];` and `$_POST['2'];` prints?

Comment: where need column name while you are providing only numbers 1 and 2

Comment: @MohammadFaisal i echoed $_POST, $currentfriend/me and $votefriend/me and they all are blank

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like this.

```
table
```

initial value

```
my_name | my_friend_name
1       | 1
```

After update

```
my_name | my_friend_name
2       | 2
```

2 or something else according to your requirements

Answer (score 0):

First of all, looks like the syntax of your queries are wrong. Your `WHERE` clause should look something like these.

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM `vote` WHERE friend = 1";
$insert = "UPDATE `vote` SET `friend`= {$final1},`me`= {$final2} WHERE friend = 1";
```

Something else to consider. In this part of your code, you are doing `$var + 0` which doesn't accomplish anything, you are better off using the original value. Also try to use the identical comparison operator (=== instead of ==) so you'll know the values are exactly alike.

```
if($vote === $votefriend) {
    $finalfriend = $currentfriend + 1;
} else {
    $finalfriend = $currentfriend;
}
if($vote === $voteme) {
    $finalme = $currentme + 1; 
} else {
    $finalme = $currentme;
}
```

Furthermore, you never want to blindly assign values to variables and try to use them. Always validate/sanitize. You should have some sort of structure like this.

```
if ($_POST['form']) {
    if ($_POST['friend']) {
        $vote1 = $_POST['friend'];
    } else {
        echo "Friend is empty";
        exit;
    }
    if ($_POST['me']) {
    $vote2 = $_POST['me'];
    } else {
        echo "Me is empty";
        exit;
    }

    //rest of your code//
} else {
    echo "form was not received";
    exit;
}
```

If your `$_POST` values are empty, obviously they are not making it from the form to your PHP script possibly because it was not submitted.

I would highly encourage you to form good habits and techniques from the beginning which keeps you from having to go back later and fix bad code (been there).